# when I trying to implement the counting sort I got this error " the problem caused the program to stop working correctly Windows

Tags: c++, counting-sort

when I trying to implement the counting sort I got this  error " the problem caused the program to stop working correctly Windows  will close the program and notify you if a solution is available "

```
 void CountingSort(int *A,int size) {
    

    int SizeC = Max(A, size);
    int* B = new int[size];
    int* C = new int[SizeC+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < SizeC; i++) {
        C[i] = 0;

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    
    
        C[A[i]]++ ;
    
    }

    for (int  i = 0; i <SizeC; i++)
    {

        C[i] += C[i - 1];
    }

    for (int j = size - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
         

        B[C[A[j]]] = A[j];
        
        
        C[A[j]] --;
    

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << B[i] << "\t" << endl;
    
    
    }



    delete[] C;
    delete[] B;
}
```

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlPol.png)

Comment: Your program has a bug -- just because the error message has the word "Windows" in it, there is nothing wrong with the compiler or Windows, and there is nothing that Microsoft will report to you about.  Therefore you are responsible for at the very least, attempting to debug the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `i < SizeC` and `i <SizeC` should be `i <= SizeC`. Otherwise, the elements with value `SizeC` won't be treated properly.
- `C[i] += C[i - 1];` with `i = 0` will result in out-of-range read of `C[-1]`. The initialization of corresponding `for` loop should be `int i = 1`, not `int i = 0`.
- The decrementing `C[A[j]] --;` should happen *before* `B[C[A[j]]] = A[j];`, or out-of-range write of `B[size]` will happen.
- This program won't work well when the array `A` contains negative values.

Fixed code (negative values are still not supported):

```
 void CountingSort(int *A,int size) {
    

    int SizeC = Max(A, size);
    int* B = new int[size];
    int* C = new int[SizeC+1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= SizeC; i++) {
        C[i] = 0;

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    
    
        C[A[i]]++ ;
    
    }

    for (int  i = 1; i <= SizeC; i++)
    {

        C[i] += C[i - 1];
    }

    for (int j = size - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
         
        C[A[j]] --;

        B[C[A[j]]] = A[j];
        
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << B[i] << "\t" << endl;
    
    
    }



    delete[] C;
    delete[] B;
}
```